# How to JSON Data Format JavaScript Serializer in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, javascriptserializer

I am writing an ASP.NET web service. I made the connection to SQL Server. The web service is using a JavaScript serializer. My JSON format:

```js
[{"ID":1,"TCKN":"19","Adi":"zzz","Soyadi":"aa"},
{"ID":2,"TCKN":"99","Adi":"user","Soyadi":"user"}]
```

But I want this JSON format:

```js
"users": [
    {
            "ID": "1",
            "TCKN": "19",
            "Adi": "zzz",
            "Soyadi": "aa"
    },
    {
            "ID": "2",
            "TCKN": "99",
            "Adi": "user",
            "Soyadi": "user"
    },]
```

**WebServices.cs**

```
  [WebMethod]
public string getTumKullanici()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = "";
    var tumKullanicilar = from result in mydb.Kullanicilars
                          select result;

    json = jss.Serialize(tumKullanicilar);

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Is this correct `},]` ?

Comment: And do you need the `pretty print`? Or just an encapsulation `users` property?

Comment: Let me know if my edit helps you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're dealing with JSON data that you need to serialize into C#, go to [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Using that site I've got your C# data model:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TCKN { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public string Soyadi { get; set; }
}
```

Next you're going to need [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

You can get that by opening the nuget package manager and searching Newtonsoft.Json

Or use the Package manager console

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Next you're going to need to deserialize that JSON..

```
string json = @"{""ID"":1,""TCKN"":""19"",""Adi"":""zzz"",""Soyadi"":""aa""},{""ID"":2,""TCKN"":""99"",""Adi"":""user"",""Soyadi"":""user""}]";

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And if you never need to serialize the C# object back into JSON... You can do this.

```
string backToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

---

## EDIT

You can achieve nesting the under users by wrapping your original object with another class:

```
public class Users
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TCKN { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public string Soyadi { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}

var root = new Root { Users = mydb.Kullanicilars.ToList() };

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Comment: I want to show only the table names.. 
So I use multiple tables, I can devote all the table names.. This happens when I apply your example                                                                            :"[{\"ID\":1,\"TCKN\":\"19,\"Adi\":\"zzz\",\"Soyadi\":\"aaa\",\"}]"

Comment: Users and Contact table "users": [ { "ID": "1", "TCKN": "19", "Adi": "zzz", "Soyadi": "aa" }] "contact"": [ { "email": "s@gmail.com", "mobile": "538" }]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the way the JSON is displayed lacks of new line chars etc - that's completely normal and desired, as extra characters are useless for services. To make the JSON more readable to humans, you could use tools that enable formatting, as f.e. addon to Notepad++ or some webapp. But for general use as data in computing I would stick to raw format without the tabulators and new lines.

Comment: I want to show only the table names.I use many tables so there will be confusion.

Comment: Users  and Contact table           
 "users": [
    {
            "ID": "1",
            "TCKN": "19",
            "Adi": "zzz",
            "Soyadi": "aa"
}]                                                                                                                "contact"": [
    {
            "email": "s@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "538"
    }]